# OpenGL Indexed and Array texture

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I have a question regarding glDraw(arrays)(elements). The thing is, most people say elements is more efficient due to vertex reuse and caching, but I try to render a terrain, each vertex with same position a different texture coordinate. THat makes each vertex unique right? So if I do not have any vertex reuse, should I prefer arrays because its much easier to implement and renders the buffer in one go compared to elements which I need to supply not only with vertex data but also an index buffer?
And is there a way to render terrains which makes it able to use elements? I just dont get how to texture the terrain properly, maybe that is the problem.

I could imagine rendering models of persons would be nice with elements, since I can supply one texture file and not need more tex coords per position of vertex. But the terrain should be rendered with arrays?

When should I choose arrays and when elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For terrain `glDrawElements` is the way to go, assuming you have a simple 2d grid, and you displace it on the vertex shader or send heights as vertex attribs. It's much faster than `glDrawArrays` for this kind of mesh.

For the textures: I don't know if you want to texture the terrain with one big texture, or more textures blended together, for example a simple grass pattern, or grass blended to snow with increasing height.

The first one is pretty easy: lets say your terrain's width is W and its height is H. You use **one big texture over the whole map.** Then the texture coord for one vertex is:

```
vec2 TexCoord = vec2(VertexPos.x/W,VertexPos.z/H);
```

For the second it changes a bit:

If your **texture** is a simple grass **tile**, or anything that you want to cover the whole terrain with, then texture coord of a vertex is:

```
vec2 TexCoord = vec2(VertexPos.x/XdirectionTileSize,VertexPos.z/ZdirectionTileSize);
```

`XdirectionTileSize` and `ZdirectionTileSize` are the dimensions of one pattern. For example you want to fetch a grass texture over the terrain with 1 meters * 1 meters resolution, and your vertices are each 2 meters away from each other, then set them to 0.5 (1/2).

For **more textures** you can define more tile-sizes, and one big texture map with each color defining one material. Example: red is grass, blue is snow, green is sand, and alpha is rock. Then you **blend the textures** like this: (You can **fetch** this big **material map** just like the one big texture)

```
color = materialmap.r*grass + materialmap.b*snow + materialmap.g*sand + materialmap.a*rock;
```

And finally my favorite method for terrain texturing is **procedural shader splatting**. I won't write it here. For example the Frostbite Engine (Battlefields) uses this. Here's a link to a very good presentation: [Terrain Rendering in Frostbite Using Procedural Shader Splatting](https://www.dice.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Chapter5-Andersson-Terrain_Rendering_in_Frostbite.pdf). In short it's like masking. Rendering the heights, normals, slopes into an FBO texture, and using it like in deferred rendering/shading.

**For quality:** if your texcoords are calculated in a shader with vertex positions on a plane (.xy, .xz), it can distort textures with increasing slope. The solution for this problem is triplanar texturing. Bottom of the page: [Generating Complex Procedural Terrains Using the GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html). In short: it projects the texture to the terrain from 3 planes (xz, xy, yz) and mixes/blends them with normals.

*Of course you can mix these texturing methods. I know it doesn't directly answer your question, but I don't think you should pass texture coordinates as vertex attribs. It's much easier defining them with big textures, tiles, or splatting. Oh, and I hope you use shaders;).*

Comment: This is very helpful! You indirectly answered a big issue of mine, how to render terrains efficiently with elements or arrays. Thanks!